# Filter Set by another Set

Tags: mdx, iccube

I want to filter a set by another set, which is returned by the event `@{date}`.
The following code only works if the `@{date}` event returns a single member (e.g. `[TIME_DIMENSION].[YEAR].[2010]`). Any suggestions how to filter if the event returns more than one member?

```
WITH SET [A] AS
    Filter(
        TopPercent(
            [PRODUCTS].members - [PRODUCTS].[all],
            80,
            [Measures].[Sales]
        ),
        @{date}
    )
```

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to achieve by the Filter function ? you want to remove from the top80 products the ones that are empty ?

Comment: I want to keep from the top80 products the ones that have a sales number on the dates specified by the `@{date}` event.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [NonEmpty](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/NonEmpty.php) function? It would return the set of non empty tuples from the set.

```
WITH SET [A] AS
NonEmpty(    
        TopPercent(
            [PRODUCTS].members - [PRODUCTS].[all],
            80,
            [Measures].[Sales]
        )
    ,@{date} * [Measures].[Sales]
       )
```